# Error during fetch details from web service in refit xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, refit

> Error: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[DynamicLayoutSample.ElementList]]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'page', line 1, position 8.

Got this error while fetching data from web service using refit in xamarin forms.below the model class

```
public class ApiResponse 
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "page")]
        public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ElementList>> items { get; set; }

    }

    public class ElementList
    {
        [JsonProperty("page")]
        public string page { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("objectid")]
        public string objectid { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("width")]
        public string width { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("height")]
        public string height { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("top")]
        public string top { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("left")]
        public string left { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("transform")]
        public string transform { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("backgroundcolor")]
        public string backgroundcolor { get; set; }
    }
```

and my json is,

```
{
    "page": [
        [
            {
                "page": "2",
                "name": "element",
                "objectid": "rectelement_1",
                "width": "29%",
                "height": "9%",
                "top": "21%",
                "left": "15%",
                "transform": "0deg",
                "backgroundcolor": "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
            },
            {
                "page": "2",
                "name": "element",
                "objectid": "circleelement_1",
                "width": "33%",
                "height": "12%",
                "top": "20%",
                "left": "44%",
                "transform": "0deg",
                "backgroundcolor": "rgb(0, 0, 0)"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Service call method,

```
ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ElementList>> result { get; set; }
result = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ElementList>>();
result = await api_interface.GetElements();
```

and this is my interface

```
interface ApiInterface
{

    [Get("/magazine_pagevalue.php?mid=1&issueno=1")]
    Task<ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<ElementList>>> GetElements();

}
```

Comment: Please write more detail in your question like your web service JSON response and your Model in which you try to deserialize.

Comment: JSON response and Model class are added to the question. Please check now

Comment: please also write web service call method where you get deserialize error

Comment: Try my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

please do follow code its work for me

```
public class ApiResponse 
    {
        public List<List<ElementList>> page { get; set; }    
    }

interface ApiInterface
{

    [Get("/magazine_pagevalue.php?mid=1&issueno=1")]
    Task<List<List<ElementList>>> GetElements();

}

var resultTask = api_interface.UserInitiated.GetElements();


var result = await Policy
                        .Handle<Exception>()
                        .RetryAsync(retryCount: 1)
                        .ExecuteAsync(async () => await resultTask);
```

Comment: Add your service call function in question

Comment: method added to the question.

Comment: Try with  remove [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "page")] and put "page" instead of  "items" and change ObservableCollection to List